# Why Apple's closure declarations missing argument labels

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, closures

As I read through the `UIKit`, most of the time I see closures *(as a function parameter)* with missing argument labels like this: `func fooClosure(fooClosure: (Bool) -> Swift.Void)`

**In some cases I can guess what it stands for, in others I can't.**

#### Example:

Take a look at one of `UIActivityViewController`'s closure (as a type alias):

```
public typealias UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler = (UIActivityType?, Bool, [Any]?, Error?) -> Swift.Void
```

What does **3rd** type stand for? I have to look at the **Objective-C** version of the code to know these are `returnedItems`.

Why it is not implemented that way: *(note the `activityItems` label)*

```
public typealias UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler = (UIActivityType?, Bool, _ activityItems: [Any]?, Error?) -> Swift.Void
```

*Edit:* 
- **Is this just a temporary state (since the Swift is not fully integrated in these frameworks yet)? 
Code is less readable without argument labels.**

Comment: Parameter names are not part of  the closure *type*.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39613272/3141234

Comment: True, I was talking about argument labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this is a function signature typealias generated by machine, and the machine isn't doing what you would like it to do. Consider the following Objective-C declaration:

```
typedef void (^MyCoolType)(NSString* __nullable name);
```

The Swift generated interface for that is:

```
public typealias MyCoolType = (String?) -> Swift.Void
```

As you can see, `name` got stripped out; it is nowhere to be seen.

Nothing stops *you* from defining a function signature typealias with internal labels, in Swift. This is legal:

```
public typealias MyCoolType = (_ name:String?) -> Void
```

But that does not happen to be how the generated interface is generated from Objective-C.

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug at bugs.swift.org if you don't like the way the generated interface is generated.

Comment: Thank you, have to deduce the meaning of these parameters is questionable choice. It did not even auto insert labels in their closures anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As of Swift 3, keywords are no longer a part of a closure's **type**, thus they don't (and can't) appear anywhere a type is expected, such as in `type alias` and `func` declarations.

See the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613272/xcode-8-function-types-cannot-have-argument-label-breaking-my-build) for more information.

Comment: They *can* (optionally) be provided with empty argument labels: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40505350/1187415.

Comment: Which, unfortunately, isn't done automatically for imported Objective C code

Comment: Code I provided in "Why it is not implemented that way:" is fine, using `_` already.

Answer (score 1):

Closures are designed to be versatile. You don't have parameter names because the function you create to pass in could be wildly different from the function someone else rights.

Remember, the parameter names belong to the *function*.

To illustrate, when I create a function, I would do it like this:

```
func getUser(for name: String) -> User {
    // Stuff here...
}
```

I add the label so myself and others know how to properly use the function.

A closure parameter is not a function, you *pass in* a function. The function one person writes could create a cheese burger, while another person could write one that rotates a view 180º and segue to a new view controller.

With an example from Apples Documentation on [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622451-animate), there is an ending closure called `completion`. As this name suggests, this function is fired when the animation completes. Now the docs *do* explain that the `Bool` value tells you whether the animation *is* complete or not, something that is not obvious from the function itself.

If your not sure what the parameter is used for (example being above), look at the docs.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sure, you can name argument labels as you want, do not have to use the same labels provided by function closures (In a closure passed as a function parameter). You can do the same in Obj-C as well. But the thing about the example above is that it is not always obvious (completion with bool) and documentation did not say a thing about it. How come?

Comment: Because it's been overlooked :(