# Using higher order functions in swift

Tags: ios, swift, haskell

I am learning swift coming from a Haskell background, I would like to translate this bit into swift:

```
match :: Int -> Bool
match = (>) 3

hasMatch :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]
hasMatch pred ns = filter pred ns

hasMatch match [1..5] = [4,5]
```

Silly example I know. This is what I have with swift:

```
func hasMatch(pred : (Int) -> Bool, ns : [Int]) -> [Int]{
    return ns.filter{n in pred(n:n)}
}


func match(n: Int) -> Bool{
    return n > 3
}

let os = hasMatch(pred : match, ns: [1,2,3,4,5])
```

Which does not compile. This is the error message:

```
let os = hasMatch(pred : match, ns: [1,2,3,4,5])

    ./hello-swift.swift:48:28: error: extraneous argument label 'n:' in call
        return ns.filter{n in pred(n:n)}
                                  ^~~

./hello-swift.swift:48:24: error: closure use of non-escaping parameter 'pred' may allow it to escape
        return ns.filter{n in pred(n:n)}
                              ^
./hello-swift.swift:47:15: note: parameter 'pred' is implicitly non-escaping
func hasMatch(pred : (Int) -> Bool, ns : [Int]) -> [Int]{
              ^
                     @escaping
```

I have two questions:

1. I have `pred(n:n)` but this assumes that `pred` names its input as `n`, which does not make sense. Do all functions have to have named inputs?
2. How would I change to the code so that it compiles

Comment: Closures lose their argument labels. It is just `return ns.filter{n in pred(n)}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613272/xcode-8-function-types-cannot-have-argument-label-breaking-my-build or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514014/why-apples-closure-declarations-missing-argument-labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func hasMatch(pred: (Int) -> Bool, ns: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return ns.filter { n in pred(n) }
}
```

You don't need parameter names if the function is a closure.

`@escaping` is a keyword in swift which tells the compiler that the passed in function will escape the current scope, so it needs to retain/release the passed in arguments (Swift, like objective-c, uses retain counting for memory management)

However, you don't need it in this case - that error was a red herring thrown by the compiler because it couldn't compile the line with `filter` in, so it didn't know whether you needed to escape or not. Looks like it plays things safe :)

As soon as you remove the `n:` and it can work out which `filter` you are calling, it knows that because `filter` doesn't need an `@escaping` closure, your method doesn't either so that error goes away.

Comment: @MartinR Just realized that - check out my edit! Thought it looked wrong, but couldn't put my finger on why. That'll teach me to blindly follow the autofix button in Xcode!

Comment: @Martin R I'm sorry could you explain why I don't need parameter names if a function is a closure? I am very confused about this whole parameter name thing.

Comment: @chibro2: It is a consequence of https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md. Have a look at the two Q&A's that I linked-to above.

Answer (score 0):

```
func mapedData(){
let bookData = ["book1":120, "book2": 150]
let mapedData = bookData.map({(key,value) in return value + 40 })
print(mapedData)
}
```

// [160, 190]

```
func filterData()
{
     let bookData = ["book1":127, "book2": 150 ,"book3": 289 ,"book4": 190, "book5": 950  ]
    let filterData = bookData.filter({(key,value) in return value < 200})
    print(filterData)
}
```

// ["book2": 150, "book4": 190, "book1": 127]

```
func reducedData()
{
    let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    let reducedData = data.reduce(0, { sum , number in return sum + number })
    print(reducedData)
}
```

//55

```
func compactData(){
       let data = [1,nil,3,4,5,6,7,nil,9,10]
    let cMap = data.compactMap({return $0})
    print(cMap)
}
// [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]

func flatMappedData(){
    let data = ["sachin"]
    let characters = data.flatMap({return $0})
    print(characters)        
}
```

// ["s", "a", "c", "h", "i", "n"]